# What is an easy-to-make dessert that goes well with Indian food?

Tags: dessert, indian-cuisine, curry

We are making vegetable curry with rice and need a dessert to go well with it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at common Indian desserts? This is a bit of a broad question for this site, as there isn't really a single answer.

Comment: I did look at common Indian desserts. I was recommended Kulfi but it takes 8 hours of freezing time. http://allrecipes.com/recipe/kulfi/

Comment: @atomiccharles: If you have an ice-cream maker, I suspect kulfi would take a lot less than 8 hours.  You can also investigate kheer (rice pudding), lassi (spiced yogurt), and simple grilled fruit.  Really, there are thousands of options.

Comment: kheer would be my first guess, but it's true -- there really is a lot of options.

Comment: There is also shahi tukdey (شاہی ٹکڑے) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_ka_Meetha

Comment: Sheer Khurma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheer_kurma . Although I would recommend some changes to the wikpedian recipe.  Spaghettini instead of vermecelli, no dates (unless its for breakfast), lots of sugar, long cooking time for thickening and caramelizing the sugar.

Comment: If easy-to-make is your priority I would go for mango lassi. It is simply mango blended with youghurt. You can also add milk to adjust consistency, or add sugar to adjust sweetness.

Comment: Kheer is a great way to go, though it does take a bit to cook. Gulab Jamun are also easy to make (if messy), and much faster to cook.  You can use powdered milk and heavy cream.  They're like donut holes crossed with pancakes and syrup -- but INDIAN!   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulab_jamun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not authentic but a rice pudding cooked in coconut milk (cardamom opt) and chilled in individual portions is lovely with fresh fruit at the table. I had it served with passionfruit -lovely.

Keep portions dainty after a full curry meal!

Comment: If you do a recipe for Kheer, I think that would make it authentic :)

Answer (score 7):

Plain yogurt.

I had it several times in Indian dish. It refreshes the mouth and takes away the the lingering of the spices from Indian curry and clear the hotness away from a spicy Indian dish.

Comment: While your answer is true, Yoghurt does not carry the psychological effect of a "dessert"

Comment: Top with honey and sweetened nuts, would that psychologically make it a desert? :)

Comment: @Midhat: in France white yoghurt, or fresh cheese are often served as dessert (often with honey or fruit)... I guess it is just cultural differences

Comment: @nico Je assumer toi ne get drunk pas on "lassi" (mix de yogurt e eau) :D

Comment: @Midhat: LOL :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little sweet by itself but a scoop of kulfi with some fresh 'tropical' fruit is absolutely delicious!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Caramel Custard.

Answer (score 0):

One *easy* option would be "Phirni".

The basic difference between *Phirni* and *Kheer* is that in *Phirni* the rice isn't cooked. It is simply soaked in milk for about 2 hours, and then it is ground to a fine paste.
While the remaining milk is cold, rice paste mixture is to be added to it and stirred properly.

It will be ready in "5" minutes when you put the vessel (containing the mixture) on the Gas with medium flame.
TIP: The mixture is to be stirred "continuously" when on Gas.

Comment: What's the flavoring?  Cardamom?  Rose water?  Almonds?

Comment: @BobMcGee Actually till last month I used to put "grated" Almonds, Cashew, and **"Pistachio"** in it. But, grating them is a time consuming thing, so I left it all together and consumed "plain" Phirni and I liked it very well too. BTW, this dish is supposed to be served cold. P.S. If you want the exact measurements of milk and rice, I can present them here.